# How can I join string variables when some might be a null?

Tags: c#

I have the following variables:

```
ac, pr, pa, co and it
```

All of these are string variables and some may be null.

Is there a way I can create a new variable called pk that is a combination of the contents of all of these variables. I was thinking simply:

```
var pk = ac + pr + pa + co + it;
```

However would this be a problem if some varibably was null. I am not sure what happens when I add a null variable to a string.

Comment: I must ask, why didn't you just try it out? Simply set some of the variables to null, then display a System.Windows.Messagebox() with the result.

Comment: Have you tried it?  Your guess worked just fine in a minimalist test program.

Comment: -1 pick up good book on C# programming, it will be better way to come to pace with this conceptual things

Comment: upvoted because the downvotes were quite harsh and this really was a bad question, but not a super, super bad question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Null strings will concatenate into an empty string. Try it and see:

```
string a = null;
string b = null;

var x = a + b;
var y = string.Concat(a, b);
```

This is a [documented feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd.aspx) of `string.Concat`, as well as section 7.8.4 of the [C# 4 language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7029) on the `+` operator using strings, where null arguments are converted to an empty string.

Comment: Is there an advantage to using Concat? Is there a case where x and y may not be the same? Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question but I just want to be sure. Thanks.

Comment: The expression `var x = a + b;`, where `a` and `b` are strings, compiles into an invocation of `string.Concat`. I showed the explicit invocation of it, but it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: Note: I slightly erred in my prior statement, by the way. `a` *or* `b` must be a string. That is to say, `var x = "hello" + 1;` would also be a string concatenation. The other operand would be treated as `object` (which boxes a value type), and the same rules apply. If it is a null reference, an empty string is substituted. Otherwise, the result of `ToString()` on the object is used for the concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `String.Format();`

```
String result=String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}",ac,pr,pa,co,and,it)
```

Comment: Why would this be any different or better than the `+` operator shown in the question?

Comment: By my understanding of the question, `and` isn't a variable name, it is just the word "and."

Comment: @Cody Gray, I don't know which one is different or better,but having switched from the C++ background I find always easy doing it with String.Format().

Answer (score 1):

There will be no problem.

If a variable is null, it will simply be converted to "", so an empty string.

If you had the following:

```
string a = "->";
string b = null;
string c = "<-";
```

And you were to add them together like so:

```
var result = a + b + c;
```

The result would simply be

> -><-

Answer (score 1):

It is fine if you add(append) a null string to another. A null string in this case will be converted into empty string.